# URL rewrite in html

Tags: html

I want to do URL rewrite in html pages.

Any help for that. every one knows about url rewrite but I found all article for pp, asp.net, classic asp. so please any one knows how to do url rewrite in html.

like wise I want to rewrite from

http://www.xyz.com/aboutus.html to http://www.xyz.com/About-us

Any help will appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: URL rewriting has to be done by the server.

Comment: As Quentin said, it's not doable with HTML. Maybe you can tell us what server you're using so that we can help you set it up server-side with PHP or ASP, or whatever you can use.

Comment: see this : - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336716/is-it-possible-to-do-a-url-rewrite-on-a-dynamic-website

Comment: You could theoretically rewrite urls (in some limited capacity) with javascript, but it would be much, much easier to just fix it on the server to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not normally huge on working with `RewriteEngine`, or `.htacess`, but according to [this blog entry](http://newmediarts.blogspot.ca/2007/01/hide-file-extensions-in-urls-with.html), you can use the following code to hide file extensions:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

Just paste that in your `.htaccess` file, and put the changes to the server (upload the new `.htaccess` using an HTTP client). If your `.htaccess` already has `RewriteEngine on`, you should skip the first line.

If you want to change the URL from `xyz.com/aboutus.html` to `xyz.com/About-Us`, you also have to change the name of the file or folder `aboutus` to `About-Us`. Another possible solution would involve just having an `index.html` file in a folder named `About-Us`, which would make the server load that file automatically once a user accesses `xyz.com/About-Us`, and wouldn't display the filename.

Comment: Hello I try that but it did not work for me. I paste this code to my .htaccess file and upload it to server but it did not work it still shows .html extension.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite urls you need to configure the webserver to do that (for example in apache with `.htaccess`.

But if you want to do that without use server configuration, a **bad** solution exists: make a folder with the name of the url and put the html into that with the name `index.php`. For example `about-us.html` > `about-us/index.html` and in links put the url `about-us`. But is a **bad** solution.